# fetch JSON data using jQuery and validate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, json

I have been using jQuery lately, but never used JSON with it.

Now, I am preparing JSON using PHP on server-side. I need to fetch that JSON data using javascript (preferred way using jQuery)

I can get JSON data by going to similar URL mentioned below

```
http://www.example.com/getjson.php?catid=1        
                    OR
http://www.example.com/getjson.php?catid=15
```

There is a file name "getjson.php" on my server, which will accept a 'get' argument as catid (stands for category id), fetches data from category table, and output data in JSON format.

**Now I need JS code (If code would be in jQuery, it would be added advantage as I badly need code in jQuery) which can fetch data from above mentioned URL, and parse it (which I believe is decoding JSON, right?).**

**One more thing, after fetching data, I need to validate whether data that I have received is in JSON format or not (It's really important)**

Category Table have following fields, which I am outputing in JSON format.

```
ID, Name, Description, ImageURL, Active, Deleted
```

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Check out jQuery's $.getJSON(); method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $.getJSON(url, data, callback);

It get data from the given url and check if it is JSON valid.

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://www.example.com/getjson.php?catid=' + $('#valueContainer').val(),
     function (data) {
         // do stuff here
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/getjson.php?catid=15',
    success: function(data) {
        // data be a javascript object that contains your already decoded json data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JQuery [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function to request your server page and pass the relevant parameters.

Then to parse your response you can use `JSON.parse()`, if it returns/throws an error you don't have valid JSON.

**NOTE** once your response has been run through JSON.parse it wont be json string any more it will be a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to retrieve the JSON:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/getjson.php?catid=1', function(data) { // success statement here });
```

Then, you can use `jQuery.parseJSON()` to verify the result. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

[`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) should do the trick.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/getjson.php", {catid:1}, function(data){
    console.log( data ); // display the JSON data in the web console
});
```

Because `$.getJSON` returns a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object) you can attach an error callback as follows:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com/getjson.php", {catid:1}, function(data){
    console.log( data ); // display the JSON *data* in the web console
    // you can then access the params via dot syntax like this:
    var id = data.ID,
        name = data.Name,
        description = data.Description,
        imageURL = data.ImageURL,
        active = data.Active,
        deleted = data.Deleted;
}).error(function(){
     alert("Error!");
});
```

---

Fun fact: Whenever you use jQuery for AJAX it adds an X-Requested-With header with the value "XMLHttpRequest" to the request. You can check for this header with your server-side PHP code and decide if you should display an HTML page or send back AJAX-appropriate data instead.

This is useful when you bind to the click event on a link. But you want the link to still work when someone navigates directly to the href.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/getjson.php?catid=1">Category 1</a>
```

JS:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    // Keep the browser from navigating to the link's href.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Because we are using one of jQuery's AJAX methods we can get data back from 
    // our server that is different than the data we would get if we navigated to
    // the link directly.
    $.getJSON(this.href, /* optional data param */ function(data){
        console.log( data ); // display the JSON data in the web console
    });
});
```